# c# vlc activex добавить в сборку

Tags: c#, vlc, activex

Добавил Vlc ActiveX в проект, как com элемент. Библиотеки подцепились работают, при установки проекта поставил добавлять dll, которые относятся к этому элементу. Но если на компьютере не установлен ActiveX, то элемент не определяется, хотя dll добавлены. Выдает ошибку пропущена директива на сборку, хотя в проекте она есть.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего вообще отказаться от ActiveX элементов. Наиболее удачным решением будет использовать библиотеку обёртку. Например:[Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]